# What exactly is a "role" in Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

What is the purpose and function of "roles" in a Capistrano recipe? When I look at sample recipes, I often see something like this:

```
role :app, 'somedomain.com'
role :web, 'somedomain.com'
role :db,  'somedomain.com', :primary => true
```

So it looks like a **role** is basically a **server** where Capistrano executes commands. If that's the case, then why would it be called a "role" rather than a "host" or "server"?

In the above example, what is the difference between the `:app` and `:web` roles?

What does the `:primary => true` option do?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Roles allow you to write capistrano tasks that only apply to certain servers.  This really only applies to multi-server deployments.  The default roles of "app", "web", and "db" are also used internally, so their presence is not optional (AFAIK)

In the sample you provided, there is no functional difference.

The ":primary => true" is an attribute that allows for further granularity in specifying servers in custom tasks.

Here is an example of role specification in a task definition:

```
task :migrate, :roles => :db, :only => { :primary => true } do
  # ...
end
```

See the capistrano website @ https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Configuration-Roles-Role for a more extensive explanation.

Comment: Also note: your line should be `:only => { :primary => true }` I think...or the `role` command in the question should use `:master => true` instead.  I believe these attributes are entirely free-form.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The ":primary => true" option indicates that the database server is primary server. This is important for when you want to use replication with MySQL, for example. It allows you to create another mirrored database server that can be used for automatic failover. It's also used for deciding on which database server the model migrations should be run (as those changes will be replicated to the failover servers). This link clarifies it a bit more: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-from-the-beginning#back-to-configuration